# Unit Testing VS 2008 Using Excel

Tags: excel, visual-studio, unit-testing, excel-2003

When using Excel (2003) to provide data for my unit tests it seems to think that when a cell has TRUE / FALSE value that it is null when there has been no preceding cell values e.g.

```
 if (TestContext.DataRow["SatisfactionExtremelySatisfied"] != DBNull.Value)
      model.SatisfactionExtremelySatisfied = (bool)TestContext.DataRow
      ["SatisfactionExtremelySatisfied"];
```

Sample Excel Data

```
DataRow  SatisfactionExtremelySatisfied
0
1
2                 TRUE
3                 TRUE
```

When reading the test data using OLEDB the cells with TRUE hold no value (when inspected in debug) but when the preceding cells have the value FALSE entered it correctly gets the values TRUE.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Are you using excel for test data because you're working on an excel app or because it makes it easy to do testing??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplify.

Save the excel spreadsheet as a plain text .csv file, and have your test framework read that.  Otherwise, you're complicating your tests by troubleshooting the nuances of reading from Excel.